# Growl Notifications for a Twitter List?

Tags: twitter

I am currently using [Twitter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id409789998?mt=12).

I would like to receive growl notifications for a particular twitter list. However it seems like the current preferences allow notification on a all/none basis.

Do we have an alternative app that offers such an option?

Otherwise I will just create another twitter account and use that for growl.

Answer (score 1):

[Tweetdeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/) is the app you're looking for! It comes with his own growl-like notifications and I use it over a year now. It's just great!

Comment: Does Tweetdock also push all already read mentions and messages on every startup? I really hate that about the original twitter app.

Comment: Nope, once mentioned, Tweetdeck will consider them as 'read' and won't push them!

Comment: Great news! The Twitter.app really sucks ever since Twitter got hold of it :-(

Comment: Did it work? :)

Comment: Yes. Behaves as expected! I just hope they'll integrate growl notifications in the future.

Comment: What I enjoy especially is being able to choose a specific location for the **trends**. Tweetdeck also shows the **explanations** to the trends.

Comment: Ok, great. So your question is solved? Or do you have any more questions?

Comment: My question is solved =)